# return matched objects in array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a .filter() method on each keyup to get back a list of objects in the following array that match the value of an input field:

```
var peopleArray = [
{
    name: "Steve",
    email: "steve@yahoo.com"
},
{
    name: "Sam",
    email: "sam@yahoo.com"
},
    {
    name: "Sarah",
    email: "sarah@yahoo.com"
},
    {
    name: "Kyle",
    email: "kyle@yahoo.com"
},
    {
    name: "Kody",
    email: "kody@yahoo.com"
},
    {
    name: "Scarlet",
    email: "scarlet@yahoo.com"
},
]
```

Here is what I'm using to search:

```
<input type="search" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search Activities" />

searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    searchPeople(searchInput.value);
})


function searchPeople(chars) {

    //Search People and return a list of JSON objects
    return //All JSON objects that matched
}
```

I'm new to this so I don't quite understand how to achieve this.

Comment: Do you want to search by name, or by email?

Comment: What is the criteria for search? If the given `chars` are included in `name`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a simple string search, you would use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to return every string containing the input:

```
function searchPeople(chars) {
  return people.filter(function (person) {
    return person.name.indexOf(chars) > -1;
  });
}
```

If `indexOf` finds the string matching `chars`, it will return a location (index) greater than `-1`. This will match the filter and keep that person.

You can expand the filter predicate to check both `name` and `email` if you'd like:

```
function searchPeople(chars) {
  return people.filter(function (person) {
    return (person.name.indexOf(chars) > -1 || person.email.indexOf(chars) > -1);
  });
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed and that was much more simple than I originally thought. You also just saved me a few hours trying to figure that out, thanks!

Comment: @KodyR. glad to help. Cory Danielson brings up a good point about case-insensitivity, though, which could be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This will search for people based on name and email. Uppercase/lowercase doesn't matter, because it compares lowercase values to lowercase values.

[**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) needs to return a "truthy" value. So basically it should return anything that is not: `false`, `0`, `undefined`, `null`, `NaN` or `""` (an empty string).

[**match**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will search for a string inside of another string and returns an array of the matched value if it's found, or null if it's not found. So if match cannot find anything, the return line is essentially `return null || null;` and since `null` is "falsy", filter will exclude that person from the result.

```
function searchPeople(chars) {
    peopleArray.filter(function(person) {
        var name = person.name.toLocaleLowerCase();
        var email = person.email.toLocaleLowerCase();
        var searchTerm = chars.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return name.match(searchTerm) || email.match(searchTerm);
    });
}
```